# Random 10 id by gender in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, random

My jSON:

```
{   
"friends": {
"data": [
{ "id": "1000002470615", "gender": "female" },
{ "id": "1000005198891", "gender": "female" },
{ "id": "1000007859390", "gender": "female" },
{ "id": "1000008308250", "gender": "female" },
{ "id": "1000009416380", "gender": "male" },
{ "id": "1000010894609", "gender": "female" },
{ "id": "1000010991284", "gender": "male" },
{ "id": "1000011095914", "gender": "female" },
{ "id": "1000014648465", "gender": "female" },
{ "id": "1000017041889", "gender": "female" },
{ "id": "1000017519651", "gender": "female" },
{ "id": "1000019029610", "gender": "female" },
{ "id": "1000019497511", "gender": "female" },
{ "id": "1000019681751", "gender": "female" },
{ "id": "1000020582845", "gender": "male" },
{ "id": "1000021389766", "gender": "male" },
{ "id": "1000022247272", "gender": "female" },
{ "id": "1000025425217", "gender": "female" },
{ "id": "1000026359294", "gender": "female" },
{ "id": "1000031258301", "gender": "male" },
{ "id": "1000031499108", "gender": "female" },
{ "id": "1000032349067", "gender": "male" },
{ "id": "1000032428345", "gender": "female" },
{ "id": "1000033101313", "gender": "male" },
{ "id": "1000033288824", "gender": "female" },
{ "id": "1000033525527", "gender": "female" },
{ "id": "1000034062687", "gender": "male" },
{ "id": "1000035232214", "gender": "female" },
{ "id": "1000035804034", "gender": "female" },
{ "id": "1000040066742", "gender": "male" },
{ "id": "1000041457943", "gender": "female" },
{ "id": "1000042302703", "gender": "female" },
{ "id": "1000043758095", "gender": "female" },
{ "id": "1000045378342", "gender": "male" },
{ "id": "1000048531666", "gender": "female" },
{ "id": "1000049731704", "gender": "female" },
{ "id": "1000050719295", "gender": "female" },
{ "id": "1000050736082", "gender": "male" },
{ "id": "1000051733891", "gender": "female" },
{ "id": "1000052976810", "gender": "male" },
{ "id": "1000053432719", "gender": "male" },
{ "id": "1000054595524", "gender": "male" },
{ "id": "1000055567339", "gender": "female" },
{ "id": "1000056180174", "gender": "female" },
{ "id": "1000056737207", "gender": "male" },
{ "id": "1000058322123", "gender": "male" },
{ "id": "1000058592478", "gender": "female" },
{ "id": "1000059646724", "gender": "male" },
{ "id": "1000062848532", "gender": "female" },
{ "id": "1000062994936", "gender": "female" },
{ "id": "1000066441440", "gender": "male" } ],
}
}
```

I need to randomly display 10 IDs according to the gender.

Like in the example below:

```
if ( $ps == 1 ) {
    echo 'Random 10 male gender IDs';
} else {
    echo 'Random 10 female gender IDs';
}
```

Comment: That's a JSON string, not an array...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$gender = 'female';
$count = 10;
$myArray = json_decode($myJSONData);
$subset = array_filter(
    $myArray['friends']['data'],
    function($value) use ($gender) {
        return $value['gender'] == $gender;
    }
);
shuffle($subset);
$newArray = array_slice(
    $subset,
    0,
    $count
);
```

Comment: What do you think of `array_rand()`?

Comment: Could be used instead of shuffle() and array_slice()

Comment: Yep, just `$newArray = array_rand($subset, $count)` could do the work! :)

Comment: @user3207012 - basic PHP 101, a good thing to learn: `foreach($newArray as $friend) { echo $friend['id'], '<br />'; }`

Comment: How to print the first id. Thanks

Comment: `echo $newArray[0]['id'];`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the result of a Facebook API. ;-)

```
<?php

$my_sorted_data = array('male' => array(), 'female' => array());
foreach ($friends['data'] as $data) {
    $my_sorted_data[$data['gender']][] = $data['id'];
}

// Then if you want a mix of female... just shuffle it
shuffle($my_sorted_data['female']);
$my_result = array_slice($my_sorted_data['female'], 0, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$array = json_decode('{ "friends": { "data": [ { "id": "1000002470615", "gender": "female" }, { "id": "1000005198891", "gender": "female" }, { "id": "1000007859390", "gender": "female" }, { "id": "1000008308250", "gender": "female" }, { "id": "1000009416380", "gender": "male" }, { "id": "1000010894609", "gender": "female" }, { "id": "1000010991284", "gender": "male" }, { "id": "1000011095914", "gender": "female" }, { "id": "1000014648465", "gender": "female" }, { "id": "1000017041889", "gender": "female" }, { "id": "1000017519651", "gender": "female" }, { "id": "1000019029610", "gender": "female" }, { "id": "1000019497511", "gender": "female" }, { "id": "1000019681751", "gender": "female" }, { "id": "1000020582845", "gender": "male" }, { "id": "1000021389766", "gender": "male" }, { "id": "1000022247272", "gender": "female" }, { "id": "1000025425217", "gender": "female" }, { "id": "1000026359294", "gender": "female" }, { "id": "1000031258301", "gender": "male" }, { "id": "1000031499108", "gender": "female" }, { "id": "1000032349067", "gender": "male" }, { "id": "1000032428345", "gender": "female" }, { "id": "1000033101313", "gender": "male" }, { "id": "1000033288824", "gender": "female" }, { "id": "1000033525527", "gender": "female" }, { "id": "1000034062687", "gender": "male" }, { "id": "1000035232214", "gender": "female" }, { "id": "1000035804034", "gender": "female" }, { "id": "1000040066742", "gender": "male" }, { "id": "1000041457943", "gender": "female" }, { "id": "1000042302703", "gender": "female" }, { "id": "1000043758095", "gender": "female" }, { "id": "1000045378342", "gender": "male" }, { "id": "1000048531666", "gender": "female" }, { "id": "1000049731704", "gender": "female" }, { "id": "1000050719295", "gender": "female" }, { "id": "1000050736082", "gender": "male" }, { "id": "1000051733891", "gender": "female" }, { "id": "1000052976810", "gender": "male" }, { "id": "1000053432719", "gender": "male" }, { "id": "1000054595524", "gender": "male" }, { "id": "1000055567339", "gender": "female" }, { "id": "1000056180174", "gender": "female" }, { "id": "1000056737207", "gender": "male" }, { "id": "1000058322123", "gender": "male" }, { "id": "1000058592478", "gender": "female" }, { "id": "1000059646724", "gender": "male" }, { "id": "1000062848532", "gender": "female" }, { "id": "1000062994936", "gender": "female" }, { "id": "1000066441440", "gender": "male" } ] } }', true);

$randommales = array();
$randomfemales = array();

$allmales = array();
$allfemales = array();

foreach($array['friends']['data'] as $key => $details) {
    if ($details['gender'] == 'male') {
        $allmales[] = $key;
    } else {
        $allfemales[] = $key;
    }
}

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
    $randommales[] = $array['friends']['data'][$allmales[rand(0, count($allmales))]];
    $randomfemales[] = $array['friends']['data'][$allfemales[rand(0, count($allfemales))]];
}
```

In this there will be 10 random males and females in $randommales and $randomfemales.